# Postgres ODBC driver versions

Tags: postgresql, odbc

On the [Postgres ODBC driver page](http://www.postgresql.org/ftp/odbc/versions/msi/) the name for each file is of the form:

```
psqlodbc_09_01_0100-x64.zip
psqlodbc_09_01_0100.zip
psqlodbc_09_01_0100-1.zip
psqlodbc_09_01_0200-x64.zip
psqlodbc_09_01_0200.zip
psqlodbc_09_01_0200-1.zip
psqlodbc_09_02_0100-x64.zip
psqlodbc_09_02_0100.zip
```

I'm trying to make sense of the file names, and haven't been able to find any documentation. The `09_01` is clearly the major/minor version and the `x64` is pretty clear. What do the middle terms, like `0100-1` mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the following in the [source code](http://git.postgresql.org/gitweb/?p=psqlodbc.git;a=blob;f=docs/release-7.3.html;h=ec63c0b399c0419cb10e00ceff55d221b8601258;hb=HEAD):

> This is version 07.05.0001. For those that don't know or don't
>   recall
>  how the versioning works, the major and minor number track
>   the latest release of PostgreSQL that the driver is expected to work
>   with. The revision number is a bit more complex. The first two digits
>   are the version number, where even numbers are development versions,
>   and odd are release. The last two digits are the build number.
>
> In other words, this driver is build 01 of development version 00, and
>   is expected to work with PostgreSQL 7.5dev. :-) The leading zeros are
>   an ODBC thing...

I guess one cannot get any better answer than this :)

Answer (score 0):

I believe those middle terms are release update  correcting minor bugs or new features.